# .is(':checked') returns always true

Tags: jquery

HTML:

```
<table id="list">
   <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" checked="true"></td>
      <td>...</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" checked="true"></td>
      ...
   </tr>
   ...
</table>
```

JS:

```
$('#list tr').each(function(){
   console.log(
        $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]').is(':checked')
   );    
});
```

Problem: the above log statement always returns true. Each tr holds some data and I want to perform an action using this data. But the user can deselect some entities which in this case is not possible because  `is(':checked')` always returns true, even if the entry is deselected/unchecked.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: But in your example they are checked.

Comment: You don't even listen to the `change` event. `each !== event`.

Comment: Your markup is wrong checked="true" is invalid, valid checked values are checked , checked="checked" and checked="" .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your 'checked' attribute has `true` as its value, so it will return `true` as even having `<input type="checkbox" checked />` will also going be checked.

I created a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Wyrdk/) with your code, with additional function to retrieve `.is(":checked")` as it's property changed.

```
$("input").change(function() {
    console.log($(this).is(':checked'));
});
```

And It shows the change. Your problem must be somewhere else.

Answer (score 4):

My guess is you are actually using this:

```
input type="checkbox" checked="false"
```

which results in a checked checkbox because `"false"` (as a string) evaluates to `true`.

If you want a checkbox to be unchecked, don't include the checked attribute.

Answer (score 2):

First you select all the checkboxes with below statement so if one is checked it will return true

```
$(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]').is(':checked')
```

Second the default value of checked should be checked="checked".